# How to clone a project from GitHub but use Bitbucket as remote repository

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I would like to clone an open source project from GitHub, but I want to use Bitbucket as my remote repository host because its private repo is free.

I don't intend to fork/pull request, but when the original project gets updated, I would like to pull the updates to my local repository and merge.

I think in the end I will need two remote repositories. (origin and upstream?)

What would be the correct/safest way to set up such environment?

Comment: I think you've already described an appropriate solution.  You will need two remotes, one pointing to gitub and one pointing to bitbucket.  The names `origin` and `upstream` are pretty typical for this sort of setup. When pushing a branch for the first time, make sure you use `-u` to set the correct remote tracking branch.

Comment: Thanks, it's great to know that I was on a right direction. I only know basic commands for git and never tried anything at this level. I've read many blog posts and articles but couldn't find anything for exact same situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just tested it with one of my projects on GitHub: [google-calendar-backup](https://github.com/christianspecht/google-calendar-backup).

First, I logged into my Bitbucket account and created a private Git repo named `google-calendar-backup`.

And then, I did the following steps:
*(Note: I'm on Windows, so the paths may be different on your machine)*

1. Clone original repo from GitHub

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/christianspecht/google-calendar-backup C:\LocalDir
   ```
2. This will create a remote "origin" in the local repo which points to GitHub.
   Since you want to work mainly with Bitbucket, Bitbucket should be the "main" remote `origin`, so we'll rename the existing one.

   ```
   cd c:\localdir
   git remote rename origin upstream
   ```
3. Go to local dir and add the Bitbucket repo as a second remote:

   ```
   git remote add origin https://bitbucket.org/christianspecht/google-calendar-backup
   ```
4. *(optional)* Show both remotes:

   ```
   git remote -v
   ```

   On my machine, I get this result:

   ```
   origin  https://bitbucket.org/christianspecht/google-calendar-backup (fetch)
   origin  https://bitbucket.org/christianspecht/google-calendar-backup (push)
   upstream        https://github.com/christianspecht/google-calendar-backup (fetch)
   upstream        https://github.com/christianspecht/google-calendar-backup (push)
   ```
5. Push all branches to Bitbucket once

   ```
   git push -u --all origin
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': christianspecht
   Password for 'https://christianspecht@bitbucket.org':
   Counting objects: 30, done.
   Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
   Compressing objects: 100% (30/30), done.
   Writing objects: 100% (30/30), 4.41 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
   Total 30 (delta 12), reused 0 (delta 0)
   To https://bitbucket.org/christianspecht/google-calendar-backup
    * [new branch]      master -> master
   Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
   ```

   *(Credit to [larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46691186/how-to-clone-a-project-from-github-but-use-bitbucket-as-remote-repository#comment80331962_46691186) for `-u` - I didn't know this, I'm still learning Git myself)*

---

That's it. Now you can make your changes and push to `origin` (Bitbucket).
And occasionally, you need to pull from `upstream` (GitHub) to get new changes from the original project.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. I will also need to set up another computer at work the same way. But since I've already pushed the codes to Bitbucket respository, I am thinking to clone this one instead of the original at Github, then add an upstream branch to Github repo. I will try tomorrow.